# Post запрос application/json

Tags: ajax, post

Появилась нужда отправить POST запрос на сервер с заголовком application/json.
Суть в том, что в ответ сервер добавляет Cookie на свой домен чего мне и нужно. 
Есть метод через ajax.
<

```js
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  url: "https://site.ru/token",
  data: JSON.stringify({a: '1', b: '2'}),
  dataType: "json",
  crossDomain: true,
  xhrFields: {
      withCredentials: true
    }
});
```

Он прекрасно работает и возвращает Cookie если не одно но, сервер установил ограничение "access-control-allow-origin" только на свой домен.

Через форму html опять же проблема, там не поддерживает application/json.

Подскажите, как я могу решить эту проблему и возможно вообще ее решить?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно стучаться на свой сервер, и уже с него curl запрос на тот, что вам нужен

Comment: Согласен, курл возвращает заголовки и "Set-cookie" но он не может их добавить. (на сколько я знаю)